# How to calculate inflation (CPI) adjusted values over different years in Excel in one formula which is pull-down able?

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula

I would like adjust earnings over a couple years for inflation.
For this I created an Excel table with columns like this:

```
Year; Earnings; Inflation; Earnings (inflation adjusted)
1999; 0.8; 0.60; ?
2000; 1.07; 2.30; ?
2001; 1.1; 2.65; ?
2002; 1.18; 1.82; ?
2003; 1.32; 1.34; ?
2004; 1.51; 2.08; ?
2005; 1.79; 2.30; ?
2006; 1.95; 1.44; ?
2007; 2.17; 2.16; ?
2008; 1.83; 3.23; ?
2009; 1.89; 0.50; ?
2010; 2.21; 1.80; ?
2011; 2.63; 3.27; ?
2012; 2.25; 2.49; ?
2013; 2.65; 2.00; ?
2014; 2.42; 1.61; ?
2015; 2.31; 0.50; ?
```

The column "Earnings (inflation adjusted)" should show the "Earnings" value, but with the inflation ajdusted over all the years until tody.

It means for example the the earnings value from 2012 have to take the inflation of the years 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 into account to calculate the todays worth of this value in the column "Earnings (inflation adjusted)".
It should show the worth of the value today, by adding every years CPI value.
This means in this case to do the following calculation

```
((((2.25 + 2.49%) +2.00%) +1.61%) +0.50%)

2.250000000 + (2.250000000/100 * 2.49) = 2.306025000
2.306025000 + (2.306025000/100 * 2.00) = 2.352145500
2.352145500 + (2.352145500/100 * 1.61) = 2.390015043
2.390015043 + (2.390015043/100 * 0.50) = 2.401965118

2.250000000 + 0.056025000 = 2.306025000
2.306025000 + 0.046120500 = 2.352145500
2.352145500 + 0.037869543 = 2.390015043
2.390015043 + 0.011950075 = 2.401965118
```

The worth of 2.25 from 2012 is today 2.4018.

My first idea was to calculate it with the compound interest formula, but the problem is that the inflation changes ever year.

I would like to us a formula which I can pull down the table, so the enter all the years manually also do not work for me.
Probably I need there some kind of matrix formula to get the result, but I dont know how it should look like.

Comment: You give no examples of what you expect the results to be.  But probably if you divide current salary by current CPI and multiply by base year CPI, you might get what you want.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added a more detailed explanation and an example with such a calculation.
I hope it more clear now what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are off by a bit.  On my computer:

```
=2.25+(2.25/100*2.49)  --> 2.306025
```

resulting in a worth of 2.401965118 in 2015, of a salary of $2.40 in 2012.

However, if that is either a typo, or due to your real numbers having some significant figures which you are not showing us, and assuming that the value you want to see in the rightmost column are the value of the Earnings of the particular year today, then the formula would be:

```
D2:  =B2*FVSCHEDULE(1,C2:$C$18/100)
```

Fill down to D18.  The above is an array formula, so must be entered by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`

Comment: This is exactly for what I was looking for!
You are right that the calculation there was not correct, because the inflation numbers which I used there had more decimal places in my calculation as I showed there.
I did fix this problem in my original question to make the example replicable for other users too.